# Is this a correct solution to the linear congruence?

Tags: congruences

I want to solve this linear congruence:

$$2x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$$
Backward substitution:
$$9 = 4 \cdot 2 + 1$$
$$4(-2) + 9 = 1$$
Therefore, the inverse is: $-2$

Now multiply the linear congruence with $-2$
$$(2)(-2)x \equiv (-2)5 \pmod{9}$$
$$x \equiv -10 \pmod{9}$$

So:
$$x = 8 + 9k$$ for an integer $k$

EDIT:

With the answers given below, the solution is:

Therefore, the inverse is: $-4$

Now multiply the linear congruence with $-4$
$$(2)(-4)x \equiv (-4)5 \pmod{9}$$
$$x \equiv -20 \pmod{9}$$
$$x \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$$

So:
$$x = 7 + 9k$$ for an integer $k$

Comment: With $x=8$ we get $2x=16\equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, so something went wrong in your solution. This is why it's good to check solutions.

Comment: You were trying to find the inverse of $2$, not $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, here goes something wrong. The inverse of 2 is 5 rather than -2.

You should compute the inverse by the Extended Euclidean algorithm or perhaps you can guess it in a simple case with small numbers like this one.

Comment: My mistake is that the inverse should be -4 and not -2, right?

Comment: @Julia Yes $-4 \equiv 5 \mod 9$, so -4 is an inverse.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to include the correct solution. Is it correct now? @wythagoras

Answer (score 1):

$$
2x\equiv 5\pmod 9 \Longrightarrow 2x=9n + 5, n\in\mathbb Z
$$
We can solve linear diophantine equation now, but LHS divides by $2$; hence,
$$
0\equiv 9n + 5 \equiv 1 \cdot n + 1\pmod 2\Longrightarrow n = 2m + 1, m\in\mathbb Z
$$
So,
$$
2x=9(2m+1)+5\Longrightarrow x = 9m + 7
$$

If you know that $2^{-1}\equiv 5 \pmod 9$, then it's much more simpler:
$$
5\cdot 2x\equiv 25\equiv 7\pmod 9\Longrightarrow x\equiv 7\pmod 9
$$